# Tagged unions and tagging using literal types

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

In TypeScript 2.0 there were introduced tagged unions. To use them we have to introduce a discriminant property in interface, for example:

```
interface Action {
    type: "ACTION"
}
```

However I'm not able to use string literal type as a discriminant:

```
let actionName: "ACTION"

interface Action {
    type: actionName <- error: cannot find name "actionName"
}
```

I'm wondering if it's a feature or a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Your string literal definition is wrong. `let` defines variable, not a type. It should be:

```
type actionName = "ACTION"

interface Action {
    type: actionName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use the following notation:

```
const ACTION: "ACTION" = "ACTION"

interface Action {
    type: typeof ACTION
}
```